# Big-Oh Notation?? Approximating the value of sum after the following code fragment, in terms of variable n

Tags: java, performance, sorting, search, big-o

Okay, so I don't know what Big-Oh is because I swear my professor didn't cover it, and I need help for something I assume to be simple asap. I know the answers to it, but she wants code for it, and I don't know how to compile it. Basically, I googled help w/ this & they just simply have the answer, w/o an example of how to get it, or they have n = 1000 or something, but I don't see that in the prompt or what n should equal to. I hope someone understands me. **Advice, please?** lol.

This is the prompt:

1) Approximate the value of sum after the following code fragment, in terms of variable n in Big-Oh notation.

2) Answer the estimated run time of the following program segment in Big-Oh notation:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n - 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n + 4; j += 5) {
        sum += 2;
    }

    sum++;
}
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    sum++;
}
```

3) Answer the estimated run time of the following program segment in Big-Oh notation:

```
int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum++;
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= n / 2; j++) {
        sum++;
    }
```

I'm used to just sticking `public static void main(String[] args) {` in front of everything, so I did this:

```
public class BigO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    public static void main(int n) {

int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n - 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n + 4; j += 5) {
        sum += 2;
    }

    sum++;
}
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    sum++;
}
    }
    }
```

Of course that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you looked at wikipedia for what big-oh notation means? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation It's basically order of magnitude behavior. So a simple for loop is linear in N, a double loop is quadratic in N. (So for the first code fragment you have n*n plus a constant, which is O(n^2).

Comment: I understand that, but what I'm saying is I think my professor wants me to put it into code and compile it to get the answer because she always told us she wants us to make code & compile it for all of our assignments. Correction: She does want us to.

Answer (score 1):

Big O notation isn't about getting the program to work.  It's about looking at the code to see how quickly the running-time of the program increases when you increase some variable (frequently the number of inputs but in this case, simply n).

Suppose that you analyse the running time of the program for successive values of n -> n=1, n=2, n-3, etc. and find that the running time is described by a linear equation like An + B. The dominant term here is the An term so you ignore the B. You can also ignore the A and say that it's order O(n).

If the running time is described by An^2 + Bn + C then it's order O(n^2).

You understand the nature of the performance by analyzing the code and determining how it's looping not by actually getting the code to run.